# How to use scan-build to scan some set of files rather then entire project?

Tags: c++, clang, scan-build

How to use scan-build to scan some set of files rather then entire project..Its giving header files error..

Comment: the documentation [here](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/scan-build) shows how to scan specific files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].